# Lua internals: how do string methods work as methods?

Tags: lua

Lua has a piece of syntactic sugar that allows for OOP methods to be implemented: the operator `:` when used as `foo:bar(biz)` is equivalent to `foo.bar(foo,biz)`. However, what I've noticed is that it is also actively used by the standard string library in this manner:

```lua
local a = "a normal string"
local b = a:reverse() -- ????????
print(b)
-- outputs: gnirts lamron a
```

The question is: how exactly is this achieved? Naturally, when you try to assume that it expands to `a.reverse(a)` it falls apart, as `a` is a string and cannot possibly contain the key `reverse`, moreover, the statement is actually equivalent to `string.reverse(a)`. My hunch was that it actually expands to `_G[type(a)].reverse(a)`, but then you remember that the same stuff happens in the `io` library on file descriptors...

Comment: Does `a.reverse(a)` actually fail? It works on tio.run: https://tio.run/##LYpJCsAgEATvvqLxpAfzgEDIW8YgQXBjHPN9IyR9q6pOg@ZM9aIEwgFNKJXzoi4cy63V1/xqtHF4AvdgyMI5nP9UW08x3qol65A2pO@4S2TpSJS5FpCa8wU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon syntax really is equivalent to the dot syntax plus self parameter. So the question is, how does `a.reverse` work?

[The Lua 5.4 manual explains](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4):

> The string library provides all its functions inside the table `string`. It also sets a metatable for strings where the `__index` field points to the `string` table. Therefore, you can use the string functions in object-oriented style. For instance, `string.byte(s,i)` can be written as `s:byte(i)`.

We can see these metatable details with the code:

```
local a = "a normal string"
strindex = getmetatable(a).__index
if type(strindex) == "table" then
  print "string has metatable entry __index:"
  for k,v in pairs(strindex) do
    local same = (v == string[k])
    print(k, type(v), "same as string."..k..":", same)
  end
end

local b = a.reverse(a) -- ????????
print(b)
-- outputs: gnirts lamron a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/haoQwEIT/5ymG/FLw8gDC0Qcp5VjrnidqIskqd09v1@RaGgghmdlvJvNGxzGHb5pBuMISfIiL3pLE0Q/W5LPnp4oDy8JCQt3MFdXudsuKGe@Q18rVr7XGVUnZZiEP9gZYVRLYQsWDEv5QYC/xhTetteq@h4ip2TF6rDTG9A/dB9WBUjnRwlqs2s/Ewv6cvursyInV1JRue91o@mnX6OJ01rnJOdvaJoPOMfa9Obcp/E7h5CLvHNP5ZVwu@HgvUwK62uhj2GTdJLUY/BglYaYlBg8yx/ED): the output is

```
string has metatable entry __index:
rep function    same as string.rep: true
byte    function    same as string.byte:    true
sub function    same as string.sub: true
char    function    same as string.char:    true
gmatch  function    same as string.gmatch:  true
format  function    same as string.format:  true
reverse function    same as string.reverse: true
match   function    same as string.match:   true
dump    function    same as string.dump:    true
len function    same as string.len: true
packsize    function    same as string.packsize:    true
find    function    same as string.find:    true
unpack  function    same as string.unpack:  true
upper   function    same as string.upper:   true
pack    function    same as string.pack:    true
lower   function    same as string.lower:   true
gsub    function    same as string.gsub:    true
gnirts lamron a
```

Comment: Literal values can have metatables? That's bizarrely interesting. Looking at the C source code for the string library, seems to be relatively hacky, and it actually didn't make sense for me at first, hence this question... creating a dummy string value and assigning it to the dummy string, which then persists across all strings in existence. That actually makes me question how metatables work at all!

Comment: Yes - You really should study the metatable functionality - Thats brings magic into Lua - One thing i can really not understand: Why dont have numbers a ```__index``` with math functions? - But not for me - I set em where i need them with: ```debug.setmetatable(math.pi,{__index=math})``` - The magic is then: All numbers have this metamethod

Comment: They work just as the C API functions `lua_getmetatable`, `lua_setmetatable` and Lua library functions `getmetatable`, `setmetatable`, plus language features which are specified to check the metatable, right? The strange twist here is that yes, literal expressions like `"word"` automatically get a metatable. Next thing to explore, maybe, what if a custom environment has a different `string` table or no `string` table at all, and how does that map to a particular literal expression's value?

Comment: @aschepler - A coder do 1% for the functions and 99% for the error handling and exceptions - Thats the reason why these functions exists: assert, error, pcall, xpcall, warn, etc. etc. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Every string in Lua (5.1 - 5.4) has a metatable with metamethod __index.
Thats the place where all string functions are present.
Here is a function that shows it...

```
-- help()
help=function(help)
dump(debug.getmetatable(help).__index)
end
```

Thats very simple, isnt it?

EDIT: Because i forget the dump function :-) ...

```
-- dump(table)
dump=function(...)
local args={...}
local test,dump=pcall(assert,args[1])
if test then
for key,value in pairs(dump) do
  io.write(string.format("%s=%s\n",key,value))
  io.flush()
end
  return true
else
  return test,dump
end
end
```

Theres a string called _VERSION - Lets have a look on it...

```
>help(_VERSION)
reverse = function: 0x565c4870
lower = function: 0x565c4ab0
sub = function: 0x565c7020
byte = function: 0x565c6d30
gsub = function: 0x565c7bb0
char = function: 0x565c4d80
format = function: 0x565c5060
unpack = function: 0x565c62d0
gmatch = function: 0x565c6ee0
dump = function: 0x565c5a90
upper = function: 0x565c47e0
find = function: 0x565c7ba0
len = function: 0x565c44d0
rep = function: 0x565c4900
pack = function: 0x565c66e0
packsize = function: 0x565c61c0
match = function: 0x565c7b90
```

Thats the reason why it works as methods with `.` and `:`